# What encryption does Apple use?

Tags: encryption, ios, iphone

With their iOS devices, Apple allows people to block certain applications through "Restrictions". I recently had an issue with my iPhone where I'm positive that I entered the correct passcode on my new phone, but the device refused to give me access. Searching around online shows LOTS of other people claiming the same thing.

I'm wondering if it's actually a bug, or whether we're all just forgetful.

The passcodes are stored in an XML file. Mine was this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>RestrictionsPasswordKey</key>
    <data>
    PKu5mw2c2qFkynodAj9rc07KQ+E=
    </data>
    <key>RestrictionsPasswordSalt</key>
    <data>
    EPHEAw==
    </data>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Through editing the file and making changes, I can confirm that the following

Key: `IxxWEBikzuZi33zUqCBnAcWAavk=`
Salt: `aSbUXg==`

Equals passcode: **1234**

Given that each passcode is only four digits, how can I decrypt my initial passcode to see if it really was what I remember it being, or if I had misentered it the first time around.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that they use `pbkdf2-hmac-sha1`. You can read how to decrypt the codes here:

http://hashcat.net/forum/thread-2892-page-2.html

Turns out I'd misremembered my passcode after all!